# Timezone always returns TimeZoneNotFoundException

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have code that works great in the emulator but on a 3gs device it crashes with a TimeZoneNotFoundException.

The reason for my code is to convert the server time (given in CET) to the local timezone.

```
var t = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName); 
//This line below crashes               
double localOffset = t.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
```

The local timezone is in my case CET.

Any idea why this does not work in Monotouch? Is it a limitation of MonoTouch? Since the code works in the emulator, I can not see that it is a programming error? I have tried rewriting this but always end up with the same exception. Also tried "TimeZoneInfo.Local" but that gives the error right away.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Issue added to GitHub https://github.com/chrisntr/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/issue/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in MonoTouch.

Under the iOS simulator it was possible to re-use the files that contains the time zone data (i.e. just like any UNIX-like system provide). However those files cannot be accessed from an iOS device, leading to the `TimeZoneNotFoundException`.

Recent MonoTouch releases (5.1.x iirc) are initializing themselves from `NSTimeZone` data so the .NET `TimeZoneInfo` will have data that match, whatever the iOS version, what the device provides.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at NSTimeZone and this method looked like it was what I need: NSTimeZone.LocalTimeZone.GetSecondsFromGMT()

Answer (score 1):

Having the identical issue, though mine originates at the point that Newtonsoft.Json is attempting to serialize a DateTime (and wants to obtain the UTC offset.)  The stack trace indicates it is calling TimeZoneInfo.Local, which throws an exception on the device (but not the emulator.)

Answer (score 1):

I just found a workaround.  I had to recompile the newtonsoft JSON with the following change to the DateTimeUtils.cs

Change the GetLocalOffset(this DateTime d) function to simply use
      utcOffset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(d);

instead of TimeZone.Local

Comment: I gave up and implemented a workaround for this in my own code. Issues like this makes me wonder about MonoTouch, but I guess I could always have written some bindings against objective-c.

Comment: Sorry I never saw this *old* post before you tweeted me. Please never hesitate to open a bug report when you get crashes or different behavior between the simulator and devices -> http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with device builds. I solved it by setting this attribute (on the mobile side). Serialization works just fine now.

[JsonConverter(typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
public DateTime? MyEndTime { get; set; }

Enjoy!

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste from MonoDevelop doesn't result in pretty formatting. Boo.